# How to change the default circle color of the radiobutton in android by changing in the code itself without using xml

Tags: android, radio-button

i need to change the default circle color of radiobutton as like below sample

```
             rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
            rdbtn.setId(i);
            rdbtn.setText(ansList.getJSONObject(i).getString("Answer"));
            rdbtn.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            rdbtn.setTextSize(14);
```

Like this i need to change the circle color. Is there any way please suggest. I dont need custom xml

Answer (score 1):

I have never set colour to the radio button, But I have set Drawable to it. See, if you can use this somehow-

```
rb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.'you image here');
```

Answer (score 0):

> pass selector dynamically as StateListDrawable makes a number of graphic
>   images to a single Drawable as

```
  rdbtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
  StateListDrawable stateListDrawable=new StateListDrawable();
  stateListDrawable.addState(new  int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},getResources().getDrawable(id1));
  stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checkable},getResources().getDrawable(id2));
   ...
   rdbtn.setButtonDrawable(stateListDrawable);
```